# JavaFX DatePicker produces SEVERE: Failed to load skin 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin'

Tags: css, javafx, datepicker, scenebuilder

I'm creating a project using Scenebuilder where there is a scene that will need a DatePicker. Switching to that scene produces me this:

```
`Dec 06, 2019 5:14:43 PM javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass
SEVERE: Failed to load skin 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin' for control FakeFocusTextField@7daa3305[styleClass=text-input text-field]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.loadClass(Control.java:124)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Control.java:720)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$5.invalidated(Control.java:680)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(StyleableStringProperty.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$5.set(Control.java:672)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:69)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:45)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.transitionToState(CssStyleHelper.java:787)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.doProcessCSS(Node.java:9647)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.access$900(Node.java:398)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.doProcessCSS(Node.java:471)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSSImpl(NodeHelper.java:192)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:93)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.superProcessCSS(ParentHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1366)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1397)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:900)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1397)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9529)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1745)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$SceneModel.invalidated(Window.java:814)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setScene(Window.java:770)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.setScene(Stage.java:266)
    at JavaBandRehearsalStudioApp/UserInterface.MainWindowController.loadScheduleWindow(MainWindowController.java:130)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Dec 06, 2019 5:14:43 PM javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass
SEVERE: Failed to load skin 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin' for control FakeFocusTextField@7daa3305[styleClass=text-input text-field]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.loadClass(Control.java:124)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Control.java:720)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$5.invalidated(Control.java:680)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(StyleableStringProperty.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$5.set(Control.java:672)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:69)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:45)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.transitionToState(CssStyleHelper.java:787)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.doProcessCSS(Node.java:9647)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.access$900(Node.java:398)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.doProcessCSS(Node.java:471)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSSImpl(NodeHelper.java:192)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:93)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.superProcessCSS(ParentHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1366)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:900)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1397)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:900)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1397)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9529)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1745)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$SceneModel.invalidated(Window.java:814)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setScene(Window.java:770)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.setScene(Stage.java:266)
    at JavaBandRehearsalStudioApp/UserInterface.MainWindowController.loadScheduleWindow(MainWindowController.java:130)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This only happens when I put a DatePicker in the scene. Removing it also removes the error. I already tried hardcoding it but it just produces the same error.

DatePicker(FX8):

[image: DatePicker(FX8)]

Upon viewing the DatePicker in my Gluon Scenebuilder, I saw that DatePicker has a'FX8' besides it, What does that mean? I tried switching my java version 12 to 8 but it just shows error in my `module-info.java` requiring that it needs java 9 above. My question is, is this a CSS error or a Compatability issue with java 12?

EDIT: Just tried removing my stylesheet and adding it again resolved the issue.

Comment: Regarding the "(FX8)", I believe that's just Scene Builder telling you that the control was added in JavaFX 8.

Comment: I see, Thanks for the info!

Comment: For some reason JavaFX 8 IS used there. [`TextFieldSkin`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextFieldSkin.html) has been moved from the `com.sun` packages to `javafx.scene.control.skin` in javafx version 9. The stacktrace is clearly indicating that java 9+ is used, since module names are present...

Comment: Your stylesheet does not happen to contain a `-fx-skin` property assignment?